# SOQL: Aggregate, Grouping By and WHERE Clauses not working

Tags: aggregate, group-by, count

This query

```
SELECT Reason, COUNT(Id) 
FROM Case 
WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Problem' AND AccountId = 'xxxx' 
AND GROUP BY Reason
```

is giving me

> Unknown parsing error:

But when I run the same query without the `RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Problem'` it works, whats the issue?

```
SELECT Reason, COUNT(Id) 
FROM Case 
WHERE AccountId = 'xxxx' AND GROUP BY Reason
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the other query works? You have `AND` before `GROUP BY`, that should not work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the last `AND`.

The right query is:

```
SELECT Reason, COUNT(Id) 
FROM Case 
WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Problem' AND AccountId = 'xxxx' 
GROUP BY Reason
```

Comment: Just found it too. Thank you!

Comment: Nice! If it helped, marked the answer as accepted so others can benefit as well